Зависит ли Random в C# от времени также как в C++?
Как мне известно в C++ srand(time(0)); с rand(); зависят от времени. У меня вопрос: в C# класс Random работает иначе или он также зависит от времени?

Почему бы не почитать помощь от отцов-создателей дотнета?

"C++ srand(time(0)); с rand(); зависят от времени" - Если не пихайть в них время в качестве затравочного значения, тогда они не будут зависить от него. А вообще есть <random>.
